# Process Builder - How Big is too Big? Can PB handle this?

Tags: process-builder, case, governorlimits

We're doing a case routing overhaul and considering process builder.

If we choose process builder it be around:
-100-150 Criteria's
 -10-30 actions per criteria
 -(Possibly a 2nd criteria with 10-30 actions per criteria)
 -(Product updates, queue routing, field updates, etc)

Q: Can process builder handle this?
Q: If so, can *one* Process handle all of this or should I break it down to something like 10 criteria per?
Q: If not Process Builder than what?
Q: Any additional advice would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can process builder handle this?

[Maybe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5). Your ultimate limit will depend on governor limits, namely, the number of rows retrieved, queries performed, DML operations executed, and/or number of records affected by DML.

> If so, can one Process handle all of this or should I break it down to something like 10 criteria per?

You can have 200 criteria nodes per process, so there shouldn't be a problem here.

> If not Process Builder than what?

You could choose to write a trigger instead.

> Any additional advice would be great.

Consider writing unit tests to make sure that the governor limits won't be exceeded. Be prepared to write a trigger if you're having performance problems (processes are not as efficient as well-written Apex code).

Comment: Thanks Fox, I was hoping that either you or David would answer. I'll relay this back to our team and go from there.